# Hadoop - word count per node

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, word-count

I am implementing a customized version of `WordCount.java` in `Hadoop` where I am interested in outputting the word counts per node.

For example, given text:

> FindMe FindMe ..... .... .... .. more big text ... FindMe FindMe FindMe

```
FindMe node01: 2
FindMe node02: 3
```

Here is a snippet from my `Mapper`

```
String searchString = "FindMe";
while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
  String token = itr.nextToken();
  if (token.equals(searchString)) {
    word.set(token);
    context.write(word, one);
  }
}
```

This code outputs

```
FindMe n
```

where n is the total number of occurrences in all the input.

How can I output the count for each node along with some kind of identifier for this node like the example I provided above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can output string + hostname at mapper so that you can have word count for each node.

```
   java.net.InetAddress localMachine = java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    String computerName = localMachine.getHostName();    
        String searchString = "FindMe";
        while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
          String token = itr.nextToken();
          if (token.equals(searchString)) {
            word.set(token+" "+computerName);
            context.write(word, one);
          }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. Is there a more convenient incremented nodeId by chance like `node01, node02, ...`?

Comment: I think to have word counts across nodes, you need to have nodename in key so that similar keys gets aggregated in same reducer.